# Download whole directory with cordova.file.dataDirectory

Tags: ionic3, cordova-plugins

I'm using this plugin from cordova, cordova-plugin-file-transfer, I followed the steps in the website:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-transfer/

I succesfully dowloaded a file with this code

```
    download() {
        console.log("DOWNLOAD STARTED");
        const url = 'URL/media/images/image.png';
        this.fileTransfer.download(url, this.file.dataDirectory + 'images/image.png').then((entry) => {
          console.log('download complete: ' + entry.toURL());
        }, (error) => {
          console.log("ERROR-FILE",error)
          // handle error
        });
      }
```

But now I'm trying to download every file in the directory /images but it's not working, I'm trying it this way:

```
download() {
    console.log("DOWNLOAD STARTED");
    const url = 'URL/media/images/';
    this.fileTransfer.download(url, this.file.dataDirectory + 'images/').then((entry) => {
      console.log('download complete: ' + entry.toURL());
    }, (error) => {
      console.log("ERROR-FILE",error)
      // handle error
    });
  }
```

Any ideas? I'm working on ionic.
Thanks!

EDIT: The console show me this error:

403 error Forbidden

Comment: "it's not working" is not a problem description. Why not? What happened? Why was that bad?

Comment: Oh sorry, the problem is that it's not downloading anything, the console shows a 403 error Forbidden, but the directory in the server is 777

Comment: Can you retrieve a list of file paths from the server (like with an API)?